# React Rollup: 'name' is not exported by node_modules/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollup

I am trying to make a library/package from my component.

Tech-stack is: React, Typescript... and a bunch of other dependencies.

I am using Rollup and when I try to build the package I get the following error:

> [!] Error: 'DisplayHint' is not exported by
> ../node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/question-common.js,
> imported by ../src/utils/answerTypeConversions.ts
> https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module

Rollup:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import reactSvg from 'rollup-plugin-react-svg';
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import urlResolve from 'rollup-plugin-url-resolve';

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: './dist/index.js',
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: './dist/index.es.ts',
        format: 'es',
        exports: 'named',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.build.json',
        verbosity: 3,
        clean: true,
        check: true,
      }),
      babel({
        exclude: ['/node_modules'],
        presets: [
          '@babel/preset-react',
          '@babel/preset-flow',
          '@babel/preset-env',
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: './node_modules',
        dynamicRequireTargets: [
          // include using a glob pattern (either a string or an array of strings)
          '/node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/question-common.js',
          './node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/question-common.js',
        ],
      }),
      resolve({
        browser: true,
        preferBuiltins: true,
        mainFields: ['browser'],
      }),
      urlResolve(),
      postcss({
        plugins: [],
        minimize: true,
      }),
      external(),
      terser(),
      reactSvg({
        jsx: false,
        include: ['custom.d.ts'],
        exclude: null,
      }),
      svg(),
      replace({
        include: ['../src/icons/**'],
        preventAssignment: true,
        // Replace ReactComponent to allow resolution of SVG files under Rollup
        ReactComponent: 'default',
      }),
      json(),
    ],
  },
];
```

DisplayHint:

```
/**
 * An indication of how clients should display a question.
 *
 * This is inferred from the answer_format and answer_display api properties.
 * Those properties should not be used directly, and clients should rely instead
 * solely on DisplayHint.
 */
export declare const DisplayHint: {
    readonly ButtonGroup: "DisplayHint::ButtonGroup";
    readonly Checkbox: "DisplayHint::Checkbox";
};
export declare type DisplayHint = typeof DisplayHint[keyof typeof DisplayHint];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `DisplayHint` is a TS type/interface, not an exported JS value.

Rollup per se is a bundler not a TS language analyzer. It cannot tell if a named export is a concrete JS value or merely a non-existing TS type, thus the reported error.

Rollup plugin order matters. To resolve this specific problem, just lift the `typescript` plugin up in order, at least before `babel`. TS plugin, if put to work first, will correctly erase TS type from JS code output.

---

**Update**

I know another trick, but it’s a workaround-ish one. The trick is to use `import type` syntax to explicitly mark `DisplayHint` as a TS type.

```
import type { DisplayHint } from "@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core"
import { otherNonTypeStuff } from "@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core"
```

This trick is not satisfying because it requires you to explicitly mark everywhere you need a TS type, and you have to separate concrete JS exports from TS type ones, like shown above. This is fine if it’s a one-off thing but if you have a large codebase it’s very tedious.

I have to add, it’s unexpected to me that original solution doesn’t work. My guess is that this module `@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core` is somehow quirky. (Why you include them as dynamic import target in the config anyway?)

It’s a JS module with `.d.ts` annotation, that I can tell, but looks like it’s a private module, I cannot see the code thus cannot dive deeper. My guess is that `.d.ts` declaration is broken, it doesn’t match up to the real export of JS code.

Anyway, I hope this trick resolve your problem. If you need me to look closer, I’ll have to ask you to setup a minimal reproducible example. With current info there’s not much I can do.

Comment: I updated the description, added DisplayHint - it looks like you are right about that DisplayHint is a "type", this solution not working for this use case... thanks anyway

Comment: That’s unexpected. It still report same error?

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issue just happening with linked library (with typescript plugin in place), in my case solution was to add the linked library to config '[external](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#external)' property. But node_modules should be treated as external anyway so not sure if this will apply

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using Vite and in my case, specifying that the module that I'm importing from should remain [external](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#external) to the bundle under `rollupOptions` in `vite.config.js` resolved the issue.